# rails pagination with tag cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, tag-cloud

im using kaminari. It's working with a chain and i have ActiveRecord::Relation object, but i cant figure out, howto avoid this error.

Code here, have trouble with stackoverflow redactor :/
http://pastie.org/1602799

Problem is when i hit tag, i got error

```
undefined method `current_page' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x9ee7cb8>
```

I seen some solution, but they for will_paginate and seems deprecated, how can i do pagination for tag_cloud properly? Without pagination everything work perfectly.

I try both kaminari and will_paginate, both give me errors :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this have any effect?

```
def tag
  @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:id]).page(params[:page])
  @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  render :action => 'index'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of us that want to see the questions code from the pastie without having to tab back and forth. (made it really hard to see what the solution was on a small screen)

```
def index
    @posts = Post.page(params[:page]).per(5)
    tag_cloud
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
    end
  end
  def tag
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:id])
    @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)
    render :action => 'index'  
  end

  def tag_cloud
      @tags ||= Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  end

View

%h1 Listing posts
-tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class|
  = link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class
```